# Droidscript and Printers

Tags: printing, droidscript

Vorrei aggiungere sulla mia App la possibilità di stampare del testo su una stampante termica Bluetooth (un piccolo ticket che contiene delle scritte es. "Hello World").

Sono in possesso di una NETUM modello NT-1809DD. La stampante funziona con il mio smartphone (Samsung Note 10) con la App del venditore (POSPrinter BT) e con altre scaricate su Google Play (RawBT print service). La stampante viene trovata (Mac Adress 57:4C:54:02:DC:3F e driver ESC/POS general) e ho fatto diversi test e tutto funziona.

In Droidscript ho installato il plugin BluetoothLE ed ho eseguito i codici di esempio, ma la stampante non viene trovata e quindi non stampa.
Dove posso trovare qualche codice di esempio o eventualmente cambiare stampante con un'altra compatibile con Droidscript)?

I did several searches on the internet but found nothing

Answer (score 0):

Droidscript does not support "Bluetooth (classic)", it only supports "Bluetooth low energy" which is not the same